# More processors requested than permitted

Tags: fortran, mpi, batch-processing, slurm

I parallelized three nested-loops with MPI. When I ran the code, an error popped up, saying 'srun: error: Unable to create step for job 20258899: More processors requested than permitted'

Here is the script that I used to submit job.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --partition=workq
#SBATCH --job-name="code"
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --err=std.err
#SBATCH --output=std.out
#---#
module switch PrgEnv-cray PrgEnv-intel
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
#---#
echo "The job "${SLURM_JOB_ID}" is running on "${SLURM_JOB_NODELIST}
#---#
srun --ntasks=1000 --cpus-per-task=${OMP_NUM_THREADS} --hint=nomultithread ./example_parallel
```

I paste my code below. Would anyone please tell me what problem is with my code? Is the MPI that I used wrong or not? Thank you very much.

```
PROGRAM THREEDIMENSION
USE MPI
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(p=15,r=14)
INTEGER :: i, j, k, le(3)
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: kp(:,:,:,:), kpt(:,:), col1(:), col2(:)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: su, co, tot
INTEGER :: world_size, world_rank, ierr
INTEGER :: world_comm_1st, world_comm_2nd, world_comm_3rd
INTEGER :: th3_dimension_size, th3_dimension_size_max, th3_dimension_rank
INTEGER :: th2_dimension_size, th2_dimension_size_max, th2_dimension_rank
INTEGER :: th1_dimension_size, th1_dimension_size_max, th1_dimension_rank
INTEGER :: proc_1st_dimension_len, proc_2nd_dimension_len, proc_3rd_last_len, proc_i, proc_j, proc_k
REAL (KIND=dp) :: t0, t1

CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, world_size, ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, world_rank, ierr)

IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   t0 = MPI_WTIME()
END IF

le(1) = 1000
le(2) = 600
le(3) = 900
ALLOCATE (kp(le(1),le(2),le(3),3))
ALLOCATE (kpt(le(3),3))
ALLOCATE (col1(le(1)))
ALLOCATE (col2(le(2)))

DO i = 1, le(1), 1
   DO j = 1, le(2), 1
      DO k = 1, le(3), 1
         kp(i,j,k,1) = DBLE(i+j+j+1)
         kp(i,j,k,2) = DBLE(i+j+k+2)
         kp(i,j,k,3) = DBLE(i+j+k+3)
      END DO
   END DO
END DO

proc_1st_dimension_len = (world_size - 1) / le(1) + 1
proc_2nd_dimension_len = (world_size - 1 / (le(1) + le(2))) + 1
proc_3rd_last_len = MOD(world_size - 1, le(1)+le(2)) + 1

IF (world_rank <= proc_3rd_last_len*proc_2nd_dimension_len*proc_1st_dimension_len) THEN
   proc_i = MOD(world_rank,proc_1st_dimension_len)
   proc_j = world_rank / proc_1st_dimension_len
   proc_k = world_rank / (proc_1st_dimension_len*proc_2nd_dimension_len)
ELSE
   proc_i = MOD(world_rank-proc_3rd_last_len,proc_1st_dimension_len-1)
   proc_j = (world_rank-proc_3rd_last_len) / proc_1st_dimension_len-1
   proc_k = (world_rank-proc_3rd_last_len) / (proc_2nd_dimension_len*proc_2nd_dimension_len-1)
END IF

CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)

CALL MPI_COMM_SPLIT(MPI_COMM_WORLD,proc_i,world_rank,world_comm_1st,ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(world_comm_1st,th1_dimension_size,ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(world_comm_1st,th1_dimension_rank,ierr)

CALL MPI_COMM_SPLIT(MPI_COMM_WORLD,proc_j,world_rank,world_comm_2nd,ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(world_comm_2nd,th2_dimension_size,ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(world_comm_2nd,th2_dimension_rank,ierr)

CALL MPI_COMM_SPLIT(MPI_COMM_WORLD,proc_k,world_rank,world_comm_3rd,ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(world_comm_3rd,th3_dimension_size,ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(world_comm_3rd,th3_dimension_rank,ierr)

CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_ALLREDUCE(th1_dimension_size,th1_dimension_size_max,1,MPI_INT,MPI_MAX,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_ALLREDUCE(th2_dimension_size,th2_dimension_size_max,1,MPI_INT,MPI_MAX,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)

IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   OPEN (UNIT=3, FILE='out.dat', STATUS='UNKNOWN')
END IF

col1 = 0.0
DO i = 1, le(1), 1
   IF (MOD(i-1,th1_dimension_size_max) /= th1_dimension_rank) CYCLE
   col2 = 0.0
   DO j = 1, le(2), 1
      IF (MOD(j-1,th2_dimension_size_max) /= th2_dimension_rank) CYCLE
      kpt = kp(i,j,:,:)
      su = 0.0
      DO k = 1, le(3), 1
         IF(MOD(k-1,th1_dimension_size*th2_dimension_size) /= th3_dimension_rank) CYCLE
         CALL CAL(kpt(k,3),co)
         su = su + co
      END DO
      CALL MPI_BARRIER(world_comm_3rd,ierr)
      CALL MPI_REDUCE(su,col2(j),1,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,0,world_comm_3rd,ierr)
   END DO
   CALL MPI_BARRIER(world_comm_2nd,ierr)
   CALL MPI_REDUCE(col2,col1(i),le(2),MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,0,world_comm_2nd,ierr)
END DO

CALL MPI_BARRIER(world_comm_1st,ierr)
tot = 0.0
IF (th1_dimension_rank == 0) THEN
   CALL MPI_REDUCE(col1,tot,le(1),MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,0,world_comm_1st,ierr)
   WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*) tot
   CLOSE (UNIT=3)
END IF

DEALLOCATE (kp)
DEALLOCATE (kpt)
DEALLOCATE (col1)
DEALLOCATE (col2)

IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   t1 = MPI_WTIME()
   WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*) 'Total time:', t1 - t0, 'seconds'
END IF

CALL MPI_FINALIZE (ierr)

STOP
END PROGRAM THREEDIMENSION

SUBROUTINE CAL(arr,co)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp=SELECTED_REAL_KIND(p=15,r=14)
INTEGER :: i
REAL (KIND=dp) :: arr(3), co

co = 0.0d0
co = co + (arr(1) ** 2 + arr(2) * 3.1d1) / (arr(3) + 5.0d-1)

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE CAL
```

Comment: add a `#SBATCH --ntasks=1000` directive to your script. (you have more than 512 cores per node, right?)

Comment: @Gilles Thank you very much for the reminding. I update my posted question with modified script file. Would you please give me some suggestions about the new error message?

Answer (score 6):

With the `#SBATCH` directives in the header of the file, you request two nodes explicitly, and, as you do not specify `--ntasks`, you get the default of one task per node, so you implicitly request two tasks.

Then, when the job starts, your `srun` line tries to "use" 1000 tasks. You should have a line

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=1000
```

in the header as suggested per @Gilles. The `srun` command will inherit from that 1000 tasks by default so there is no need to specify it there in this case.

Also, if `${OMP_NUM_THREADS}` were not 1, you would have to specify the `--cpu-per-tasks` in the header as a `SBATCH` directive otherwise you will face the same error.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. There are 32 CPUs on each node in my cluster. I have already modified the script files and submitted the job again. However, I still got an error message. I update my posted question with the new error message. Would you please give me some more suggestions?